# Usage of two api requests at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, youtube-api

I am trying to make two diffrent calls to youtube api. One where I search for videos and one where I get the video length of the videos I get in my search result. At the moment this is what I get:

[image]

My first result is one Object with 15 items. Other objects are added by using the first 15 videos id and looping them. However since it's 15 new objects the index when I later loop them is always 0. As you can see on my first data I get 15 items and then my loop works just as intended, however then I get responses of those 15 items Id. Which puts them in 15 new objects. Can I group those objects as one or how should I loop my new 15 objects so the index isn't always 0?

```
$.each(svaret.items, function(index, item) {
    var dur = moment.duration(item.contentDetails.duration);        
    $("#result > li").eq(index).append(dur);
});
```

The problem with index always being 0 is that all the videos length gets placed in my first children.
[image]

Otherwise if I'm not able to make two different calls like this how should I do instead? Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#formen").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#result").html('');
            var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                order: "viewCount",
                part: "snippet",
                type: "video",   
                q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"), 
                maxResults: 15
            });
        
        request.execute(function(response) { 
            var results = response.result; 
            console.log(results);

            $.each(results.items, function(index, item) { 

                var tidId = item.id.videoId;
                var tid = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
                    part: "contentDetails",
                    id: tidId
                });

                tid.execute(function(response) {
                var results = response.result; 
                console.log(results);
                $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {
                    $.get("items.php", function(data) {  
                    $("#result").append(tplawesome(data, [{"tid":item.contentDetails.duration}])); 
                    
                });
                });

                });

                        
                $.get("item.php", function(data) {  
                    $("#result").append(tplawesome(data, [{"title":item.snippet.title, "yturl":item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url, "videoid":item.id.videoId, "channelTitle":item.snippet.channelTitle}])); 

                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 code snippets you posted are a little confusing because they don't match, but I think I get the idea. The problem is that when you send the request inside the outer `$.each(...)` to get the length of each video, only one video is ever returned (hence index 0 for every video). You are making 15 API requests inside the outer `$.each(...)`. One solution is to append to `#result` only one time (which will probably require you to change your template). Note that I renamed the `item` argument in both of the `$.each(...)` functions so that we can get information from both API responses inside the inner `$.each(...)`.

```
...
$.each(results.items, function(index, video) { 

  var tidId = video.id.videoId;
  var tid = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
    part: "contentDetails",
    id: tidId
  });

  tid.execute(function(response) {
    var results = response.result; 
    console.log(results);
    $.each(results.items, function(index, detail) {
      $.get("item.php", function(data) {
        $("#result").append(tplawesome(data, [{
          "tid":detail.contentDetails.duration,
          "title":video.snippet.title, 
          "yturl":video.snippet.thumbnails.high.url, 
          "videoid":video.id.videoId, 
          "channelTitle":video.snippet.channelTitle
        }])); 
      });
    });
  });
});
...
```

Another solution, which would require a bit more refactoring, is to store the `tidId` as a [data-tid attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) on the `<li/>` element and then to select the proper `<li/>` before adding the length (e.g. `$('#result > li[data-tid="[VIDEO TID]"').append(dur);`).

Comment: Oh, you are right forgot to change the second snippet. But you understood the problem correct I wanted to merge the calls togheter but didn't know how to acheive it. Thanks alot for your answer makes sense now!